# Почему в HP установлена не та память?

Tags: память, ноутбук, hp

Нашел старый ноутбук, решил дать ему вторую жизнь - купил ссд, решил добавить оперативной памяти т.к. 4гб в современном мире явно недостаточно. Процессор у этого ноутбука, HP, QuadCore Intel Pentium N3540, 2666 MHz (32 x 83). Погуглил, нашел его характеристики и обнаружил, что он поддерживает DDR3L с частотой 1333гц. Проблема в том, что сейчас здесь с завода установлен Kingston HP687515-H65-MCN 4гб с частотой 1600гц и типом DDR3. Вопрос: это ошибка HP ставить такое и что будет если я поставлю не 1600гц как с завода, а то, что требует процессор?

Comment: Скорее всего ничего не будет, просто память работает на заниженной частоте

Comment: На таких низких частотах объем вроде мало на что влияет. Лучше оставить как есть и просто не устанавливать слишком новый софт. (А еще на линуксе его сделать.)